# Texture Quality - World of Warcraft Vanilla

Tags: image, lua, textures, world-of-warcraft, tga

Textures. This is something that has been bothering me since I started messing with them.
More specifically, their quality in World of Warcraft Vanilla.

I searched and researched it over and over again, tried it in so many ways but it's just never perfect.

The game only accepts the file formats BLP and TGA which I never get them to be as good as PNG.
I'm not sure if the issue is the converters I use (I have tried multiple ones) or if it's actually impossible.

Here's an example:

**lua code**

```
local Frame = CreateFrame("Frame")
Frame:SetPoint("CENTER", 0, 0)
Frame:SetWidth(82)
Frame:SetHeight(82)
local Texture = Frame:CreateTexture()
Texture:SetAllPoints()
-- 82 / 128 = 0.640625
Texture:SetTexture("Interface\\AddOns\\MyAddOn\\image.tga") -- .blp .tga
Texture:SetTexCoord(0, 0.640625, 0, 0.640625)
```

**image.png**

[image: image.png]

**image.blp** (in-game look)

[image: image.blp]

**image.tga** (in-game look)

[image: image.tga]

[PNG to BLP converter](http://www.ac-web.org/forums/showthread.php?153646-How-to-convert-png-into-blp-file#post1696425) that I used in this case.

[PNG to TGA converter](https://convertio.co/pt/png-tga/) that I used in this case.

[image.blp](https://ufile.io/36e45) file.

[image.tga](https://ufile.io/056c1) file.

Resuming: I want to have an in-game texture that is 100% (every pixel) like the original PNG image.

Comment: WoW uses 3D-engine, so it will never display your picture exactly.  The picture will be post-processed by the engine (for example, by anti-aliasing)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: Damn it, that's what I was afraid of, the impossible part. I guess the only true way would be to have a texture for each pixel with the RGBA instead of a image path, lol. I know that's a horrible ideia. :)